# Change Twenty Twelve's comment form in a child theme

Tags: child-theme, comment-form, theme-twenty-twelve

I have a custom child theme of Twenty Twelve.

I want to change the text "Leave a reply" to "Leave a comment", and also remove the website field from the comments form.

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just for your information as well, have a look at one of my answers [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138132/31545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters in custom functions to modify the default output of the comments form via your child themes functions file.

**Modify the comment form "Leave a reply" text.**

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpsites_modify_comment_form_title' );
function wpsites_modify_comment_form_title( $defaults ) {
$defaults['title_reply'] = __( 'Leave a Comment' );
return $defaults;
}
```

**Remove The Website URL Field From Comment Form**

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'wpsites_remove_website_url_field');
function wpsites_remove_website_url_field($fields) {
if(isset($fields['url']))
unset($fields['url']);
return $fields;
}
```